# Deserialize JSON from request body with dynamic keys

Tags: c#, json, rest, .net-6.0, json-deserialization

I have a Rest API that accepts a JSON model consisting of its fields are dynamic GUIDs.

I tried multiple models and in all of them, I got an error.

This is the JSON:

```
{
   "meta_data": {
       "name": "myname"
   },
   "1122413f-2887-4789-a112-31d003f2703a": {
       "ipadd": "1.1.1.1",
       "host": "host"
   },
   "4432313f-2887-4789-a222-31d41231233a": {
       "ipadd": "1.2.1.1",
       "host": "h3st"
   }
}
```

and this is the model:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("meta_data")]
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<Guid, DeviceInfo> Devices { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceInfo
{
    public string IpAdd { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller:

```
[FromBody] RootObject jsonObj
```

The `jsonObj` only contains the `Metadata` and the dynamic field is always empty.

What can I do to overcome this?

It accepts when I send it under `Devices`:

```
"Devices": { 
     "123...."
}
```

but this is not what I need.

Comment: That is a bad json design ,our dynamic key belongs itself in a fixed tag

Comment: It would work in this way if the dynamic content was inside the "Devices" property, eg: `"devices": { "some-guid": {...}, "some-guid2": {...} }`. If you don't want to nest the structure, you probably have to create [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: @nbk agree. what this is a part of a config that we already have...

Comment: @AdrianKokot yeah I know that about the devices option, but as I said - we prefer not to use it... regarding the Custom Model Binding - it looks like a big solution. just wanna see first if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .NET Core 3 and above, you can work with [`JsonExtensionDataAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute?view=netcore-3.1) from *System.Text.Json.Serialization*.

You should add a new property for receiving the additional JSON element as `Dictionary<string, JsonElement>`.

> The dictionary's TKey value must be String, and TValue must be JsonElement or Object.

And assign it to the `Devices` property with some data conversions.

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Linq;

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonPropertyName("meta_data")]
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement> Extension { get; set; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Dictionary<Guid, DeviceInfo> Devices 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (Extension == null)
                return null;

            return Extension.ToDictionary(x => Guid.Parse(x.Key), v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DeviceInfo>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(v.Value)));
        }
    }
}

public class DeviceInfo
{
    [JsonPropertyName("ipadd")]
    public string IpAdd { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("host")]
    public string Host { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

---

If you are using *Newtonsoft.Json* as the default serialization library/tool in your API/MVC application:

```cs
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

You need to use the attributes/deserialization ways from *Newtonsoft.Json*.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("meta_data")]
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> Extension { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Dictionary<Guid, DeviceInfo> Devices
    {
        get
        {
            if (Extension == null)
                return null;

            return Extension.ToDictionary(x => Guid.Parse(x.Key), 
                v => JObject.FromObject(v.Value)
                    .ToObject<DeviceInfo>());
        }
    }
}

public class DeviceInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("ipadd")]
    public string IpAdd { get; set; }

    public string Host { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Sample Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/diERAj)

Comment: Also, you may consider creating a class for this request body, to avoid the dependencies from this current class (affected) in other places.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it's working when you deserialize using JsonSerializer.Deserialize but in case of Rest when I get it as a parameter - it says that the extension is null and therefor cannot Deserialize Devices...I dont know why but it looks like the Deserialization is differ somehow in the methods of the controller

Comment: Hi apologize for late reply, I had update my answer with recording. I suspect that you might use Newtonsoft.Json as default serialization (`services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()`)? If yes, that possibly result that the deserialization result is not worked correctly. In that case, either you should use the *System.Text.Json* as default serialization library/tool in your API/MVC project, or you need to use the attributes, deserialization way from *Newtonsoft.Json*, for example `[JsonProperty]` instead of `[JsonPropertyName]`.